# Websocket failed in live server , WebSocket connection to 'wss://my_domain.com:8001/' failed:

Tags: python, django, websocket

I am adapting websocket in django app, it was working but I don't know what happened it failed now. I used different channel layer code in live server and in local server. Any Idea about this problem?

notification.js

```
const ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
if (ws_scheme == 'wss')
        ws_path = ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + ":8001/";
else
        ws_path = ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host;
const notificationSocket = new WebSocket(ws_path);
```

routing.py

```
import os
from decouple import config
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import re_path, path

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", f'{config("PROJECT_NAME")}.settings')
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from chatapp.consumers import ChatConsumer
from notification.nconsumers import NotificationConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
   "http": django_asgi_app,
   'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
      AuthMiddlewareStack(
      URLRouter([
        path('chatapp/<int:room_id>/', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
        path('', NotificationConsumer.as_asgi()),
    ])
   )
 ),
})
```

asgi.py

```
import os
import django
from decouple import config
from channels.routing import get_default_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", f'{config("PROJECT_NAME")}.settings')
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

consumers.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from chatapp.models import UnreadChatRoomMessages
from notification.models import Notification

class NotificationConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
       await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, code):
       pass
```

settings.py

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'channels',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'chat',
     'customer',
     'notification',
     'rest_framework',
     'rest_framework.authtoken',
    ]
```

I used this in live server

```
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
        "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
           "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
           },
          },
         }
```

and I used this is local server

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
    "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
      }
  }
```

Related packages installed:
channels 3.01
channel-redis 3.3.0